# Paypal payement failure in test account in java

Tags: java, payment-gateway, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to develop application in Paypal DoDirectPayment method am creating testing sandbox account and use the following code with my own API credentials  but i get acknowledgement is failure ...

If any one know how to rid out this issue share to me.,

Thanks  in advance.

```
public class DoDirectPayment 
{
private NVPCallerServices caller = null;

public String DoDirectPaymentCode(String paymentAction,String amount,String cardType,
                            String acct,String expdate,String cvv2, String firstName,
                            String lastName, String street, String city, String state, 
                            String zip, String countryCode)
{
    NVPEncoder encoder = new NVPEncoder();
    NVPDecoder decoder = new NVPDecoder();

    try
    {

        caller = new NVPCallerServices();
    APIProfile profile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile();
        /*
         WARNING: Do not embed plaintext credentials in your application code.
         Doing so is insecure and against best practices.
         Your API credentials must be handled securely. Please consider
         encrypting them for use in any production environment, and ensure
         that only authorized individuals may view or modify them.
         */
    // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, API operation and version.
        profile.setAPIUsername("sdk-three_api1.sdk.com");
        profile.setAPIPassword("QFZCWN5HZM8VBG7Q");
        profile.setSignature("AVGidzoSQiGWu.lGj3z15HLczXaaAcK6imHawrjefqgclVwBe8imgCHZ");
        profile.setEnvironment("sandbox");
        profile.setSubject("");
        caller.setAPIProfile(profile);

        encoder.add("VERSION", "51.0");
        encoder.add("METHOD","DoDirectPayment");

    // Add request-specific fields to the request string.
        encoder.add("PAYMENTACTION",paymentAction);
        encoder.add("AMT",amount);
        encoder.add("CREDITCARDTYPE",cardType);     
        encoder.add("ACCT",acct);                       
        encoder.add("EXPDATE",expdate);
        encoder.add("CVV2",cvv2);
        encoder.add("FIRSTNAME",firstName);
        encoder.add("LASTNAME",lastName);                                       
        encoder.add("STREET",street);
        encoder.add("CITY",city);   
        encoder.add("STATE",state);         
        encoder.add("ZIP",zip); 
        encoder.add("COUNTRYCODE",countryCode);

    // Execute the API operation and obtain the response.
        String NVPRequest = encoder.encode();
        String NVPResponse =(String) caller.call(NVPRequest);
        decoder.decode(NVPResponse);

    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return decoder.get("ACK");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DoDirectPayment obj=new DoDirectPayment();
    System.out.println(obj.DoDirectPaymentCode("Authorization ", "1", "Visa", "1234123412341234", "122012", "123", "testname", "testname", "chennai", "chennai", "TX", "77570", "US"));

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the PAYMENTACTION parameter:
"Authorization " should be replaced with "Authorization" (just remove redundant space at the end)

Comment: And you still seem to be using the default API username. Set up your own by signing up as a developer on https://developer.paypal.com/ and create a preconfigured US Website Payments Pro account.
Note: If you get 'Invalid merchant configuration', log a ticket at https://www.paypal.com/mts and ask them to enable Website Payments Pro on your Sandbox seller account. Ensure you provide them with the API username.